# Prepopulating html form from $_GET

Tags: php

I'll start by saying I think this is fairly basic. New to web dev.
Scenario: You're signing up for my site but you enter an already-taken username so you get sent back to the same page (probably with an error message) to try again.
You shouldn't have to renter say your email.
What I have works but I thought there was an easier way to pull from $_GET and prepopulate the form.
So I am wondering if I can replace this block of php code with something easier, or if this is how you're supposed to do it:

```
  <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST" id="signUpForm">
      <?php
          if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
              echo '<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username" value='.$_GET['uid'].'>';
          }
          else {
              echo '<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">';
          }
      ?>
      <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Probably better to do it with Sessions as apposed to `$_GET`. However if you want a quicker alternative you could use a quick one-liner like this for example; `<?php echo '<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username" value='.( ( isset($_GET['uid'] ) ) ? $_GET['uid'] : '' ).'>'; ?>`.

Comment: A very common approach is to send the form to the same script that generated it in the first place. If all validations pan out, you proceed with your user registration (could be put into a separate file that gets included), and if not, you show the form again. In this scenario, you have all the values you need to prefill it in $_POST, and don't need to send anything around via GET or store it into a session.

Comment: Learn more about CSRF before going forward with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST" id="signUpForm">
  <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username" value="<?= $_GET['uid']; ?>">
  <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

This way is more better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution only works in my scenario given, but the first time they go to the page (i.e. before $_GET['uid'] is defined) the inserts an error message "<br /><b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key " into the value of that input which is why I needed the if statement.

Comment: use error_reporting(0); okay then